# Container storage in container optimized OS images

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to build a Container Optimized VM in Google Cloud to host a Docker container. This Docker container needs storage but the optimized container VM images have almost no writeable storage. I then created a persistent disk to attach to the VM to mount in the container, but the VMs /etc is also read only, so I'm unable to write to fstab, OR mount the disk anywhere in the filesystem. How is this supposed to be accomplished in a VM that is designed specifically to host Docker containers?

Answer (score 0):

The storage space in the instances is independent of the image used.
You can change the boot disk size on [creation time](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#publicimage) or [later](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd). This will allow you to have more storage space in the instance.
If you want to use Kubernetes Engine it is also possible to change the boot disk size on creation time.

Comment: So, it's not possible to isolate container data to a dedicated disk?

Comment: It is possible, you can add persistent disks to the nodes (VMs) and mount them (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#create_disk). Then, add them as volumes for the containers (https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume).
You asked for more space in nodes boot disk, but now you want to specifically mount a separate disk space (which is a different case).
It would also help if you provide the product you are using (GCE or GKE) and, if you are using some orchestration software like Kubernetes in case of GCE.

Comment: "You asked for more space in nodes boot disk, but now you want to specifically mount a separate disk space" 

In my original question I stated: "I then created a persistent disk to attach to the VM to mount in the container, but the VMs /etc is also read only, so I'm unable to write to fstab, OR mount the disk anywhere in the filesystem" So my original question is the same: How do I mount a separate disk specifically for container storage to the container optimized host? I'm using GCE VMs only, I have no need for any Kubernetes orchestration.

Comment: You should note that you must mount the attached disks at the /mnt/disks directory. There are several portions of the file system re-mounted as writable: /tmp, /run, /media, /mnt/disks and /var/lib/cloud.
You can find more details in the official documentation here:

https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/security